# How to return two values when using when exists in SQL

Tags: sql

In the `ot_notes` table there are different tasks for each job. This specific job has 20 rows. I need to find 'Weld_Complete', if it doesn't exist I am looking for 'Weld_Start'. This code works the way I want it too, but I also need to return the job number, so I can link it to another query. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ot_notes) 
          THEN (SELECT task 
                FROM ot_notes 
                WHERE job = '61249' AND task = 'Weld_Complete') 
       ELSE
          CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ot_notes) 
                THEN (SELECT task 
                      FROM ot_notes 
                      WHERE job = '61249' AND task = 'Weld_Start') 
             ELSE ' ' 
          END 
    END AS weld
```

The following query gives me all tasks for job 61249: SELECT job, task from ot_notes WHere job = '61249'. This is different for each job. I need to find Weld_Complete, if it's not there, I need to look for Weld_Start, or find if neither is there. I need both he job and task fields. The above query gives me what I want, except job.

```
job     task
-----   -----------
61249   Update_Date
61249   Weld_Start
61249   Paint_Start
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Ship_Complete
61249   Update_Date
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Paint_Complete
61249   Weld_Complete
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Ship_Partial
61249   Update_Date
61249   Note
61249   Note
61249   Note
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your query conditions is very weirds ... you ask `WHEN  EXISTS condition ELSE WHEN EXISTS condition`

Comment: I have one field in Excel where the result of this query goes. If welding is complete, I need to put that in Excel, If welding is not complete, but has already started then I need to put Weld_Start in Excel. If welding has not started, the Excel field stays empty. In this example job welding is finished. I couldn't find another way to get the result but with the nested Exists. The problem is that I don't only need the task, but the job number to link it to another query.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one row where `'Weld_Complete'` is prioritized over `'Weld_Start'`, then you an use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT task
FROM ot_notes
WHERE job = '61249' AND task IN ('Weld_Complete', 'Weld_Start') 
ORDER BY (task = ''Weld_Complete') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The following query gives me all the tasks for job 61249: SELECT job, task from ot_notes WHere job = '61249'

Answer (score 0):

If you you want to get all jobs that task value is 'Weld_Complete' or 'Weld_Start' (according to their priority), you can use this query.

```
;WITH tasks
AS (
    SELECT * FROM 
        (VALUES(1,'Weld_Complete'), (2,'Weld_Start')) tasks (priorty, task)
) 
, CTE AS (
select 
    n.* 
    from ot_notes n 
        inner join tasks t on n.task  = t.task
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: The following query gives me all tasks for job 61249: SELECT job, task from ot_notes WHere job = '61249' . Need to find Weld_Complete, if it's not there, I need to look for Weld_Start, or find if neither is there. I need both fields. My query gives me what I want, except job.   job task
61249 Update_Date
61249 Weld_Start
61249 Paint_Start
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Ship_Complete
61249 Update_Date
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Paint_Complete
61249 Weld_Complete
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Ship_Partial
61249 Update_Date
61249 Note
61249 Note
61249 Note

Comment: I guess you need 'Weld_Complete' and 'Weld_Start' tasks same time if possible. I updated the script, could you try again?

Comment: It should be one or the other. I need to put the value in an Excel spreadsheet. Either there's nothing in task that has Weld* in it, then I put a space in Excel. If Weld_Start is there, but not Weld_Complete then I put Weld_Start in Excel, but if welding is already completed, then I need to put Weld_Complete in the spreadsheet. My original query works the way I want it, but I don't know how to get the job number as well.

Comment: I tried your query but it never gives 'Weld_Start'. Because first case everytime returns true. Are you sure your query working correct?